# How to access a json POST data in Flask RESTful API app

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, flask-restful

I'm currently stuck trying to get access to a POST json data in a flask RESTful API app. The POST data is simply a Pandas dataframe converted into a json object with the `pandas.to_json()` method.

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# Creation Of Main Endpoint Classes
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):

        # Get POST data as json & read it as a DataFrame
        new_x = request.get_json()

        current_data = pd.read_json(new_x)
        return {'message': 'POST data read successfully'}

# Addition of the Endpoint Classes As Endpoints For The RESTFul API
api.add_resource(Test, '/api/v1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After making a POST request to this Test endpoint, I get a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value` error. The post is made with requests python library as:

```
import requests
new_json = df.to_json()
post_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1'
post_r = requests.post(url=post_url, data=new_json_orient)
print(post_r.json())
```

The stack trace seems to point out that `request.get_json()` returns a None with `<class 'NoneType'>`. Pandas, as a result, can't read the None. Pandas and I are missing the location of the POST data.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2019 13:06:56] "POST /api/v1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\Documents\..\app.py", line 35, in post
    current_data = pd.read_json(new_x)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 413, in read_json
    path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression,
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 232, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the new_json POST data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At what point do you get this error? While parsing the response (`post_r.json()`) or converting request to json (`request.get_json()`)? A complete stacktrace would leave no space for this comment, indeed.

Comment: @vahdet I will edit the question with the trace. I get it at `request.get_json()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most probably because the `POST` method does not contain any info for the `Content-Type` of it.

1. If the `requests` version is newer than 2.4.2, you can use `json` instead of `data` for post body (see [doc details](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) here). This will automatically set the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`:

```py
post_r = requests.post(url=post_url, json=new_json_orient)
```

2. If requests of your use is older, you can explicitly set the header value as:

```py
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
post_r = requests.post(url=post_url, data=new_json_orient, headers=headers)
```

P.S. For more about `Content-Type` header mentioned so much in this post, here's the link for [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Comment: It works! Switching from data to json did the trick. I owe you one!